# Работать учителем (–) не лёгкая задача

Tags: тире

Как правильно?

1. Работать учителем – не лёгкая задача.
2. Работать учителем не лёгкая задача.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***Работать учителем – не лёгкая задача.***

**[Розенталь, пункт 2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)**

Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба они выражены неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом) или если один из главных членов выражен формой **именительного падежа** существительного, а другой — **неопределенной формой** глагола:
О решённом говорить — только путать (М. Г.);  ***Чай пить — не дрова рубить*** (Посл.);

Наличие частицы ***НЕ*** не влияет на выбор тире, так как это правило относит **к пункту 1**: Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены существительными **в форме именительного падежа.**

Comment: А правда, что в предложении «Самое главное – практиковаться» тире можно объяснить тем, что *самое главное* здесь – это субстантивированное прилагательное?

Comment: Да, этот вариант корректный.  Другой возможный вариант - обособление вводного сочетания с помощью тире, но его сложнее доказывать.